# How to guess charset of a process output in python on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, character-encoding

I'm running a wmic command in subprocess.run on a french windows server 2012 R2 ( also on a windows 2016 Datacenter with same results ).

I've tried decoding the output of the answer with the following charsets with no avail to view the accentuated characters : cp1252 - cp1257 - iso8859-1 - utf-8 - latin-1 - cp850

```
COMMAND = 'wmic /node:\'' + host + '\' /user:' + user  + ' /password:\'' + passwd + '\' ' + requestWmi +' /format:csv'

if verbose: 
        print( 'COMMAND : ' + COMMAND ) 

try:
    myprocess = subprocess.run( COMMAND, capture_output=True, text=True, encoding='cp1252', errors='ignore', timeout=60 ) 
    

except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    
    return "Timeout de la commande( 60s )"  

stdout = myprocess.stdout
```

If I don't put the errors ignore I get :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 48: character maps to <undefined>\r
```

With the errors ignore I get wrong characters for the accentuated ones :`,H“te systŠme de diagnostics` instead of "Hôte système de diagnostics" ( using cp1252 )

I'm using python 3.9.4

So how can I guess the right charset that windows is using for the wmic output ?

Thanks for your inputs !

Comment: It's a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `"Hôte système".encode('cp437').decode('cp1252')` returns `'H“te systŠme'` so try `encoding='cp437'` in  `subprocess.run` (merely a workaround).

Comment: It works, thanks ! You're a lifesaver ! I was looking for the right codepage but didn't know where to look.